# How many tasks for the "Service to the Empire" Event & what are the rewards?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

For the new event, "Service to the Empire", is there a finite number of tasks?

If so, what is that and how many medals are required?

Also, if anyone has been keeping track, what are the requirements and rewards for each level?

I am currently on the third (?) level, which requires 500 medals and rewards players with a Recruiting Officer VIP.  It appears that the next level rewards Bux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Medals | Reward
----------------------------------------------------------
  100     Costume
  250     (VIP) Level Upgrader
  500     (VIP) Recruiting Officer
  975     Imperial Bux
 1200     R2-Q5 / R4-I9 / R5-J2 (All in one package)
 1725     Imperial Marches (1)
```

1. I believe it is because I am just into it and so, it's still a black rectangle. Sure looks like it though. (as per [Natalia's][2] suggested edit)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure at what amount of medals, but eventually you'll get 3  special characters r2-q5,  r4-i9, and r5-j2.  You'll get them after the Bux reward.  After that you 'll  finally get a new retail floor called imperial marches that you can build.  It has a scene that is opened by one of the special characters.  After you get the Imperial Marches, there are no more imperial assignments.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you provide a bit more information? This answer is a little brief.

Comment: Hopefully that's better - sorry for being vague - new to the board - thanks for your guidance

Comment: No more Imperial Assignments or no more Service Medals? They don't seem connected.  Completing Imperial Assignments does not get you Imperial Service Medals.

Comment: Completed imperial assignments will yield coins , not medals after assignments are completed.  There are no challenges out there after imperial marches that reward you with non-$ rewards

Comment: Imperial Assignments don't give you medals to start with.  Only stocking the Imperial Levels gives medals.